# How can I add python support to vim 7.4 on a Centos 7 box?

Tags: python-2.7, vim, centos

I've tried several solutions found on google search, but nothing seems to work.  Here is a shot of my vim --version and I currently have python 2.7.5 installed:

```
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
-balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
-browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     -tcl
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+cindent         +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
-clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
-clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      -toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   -perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       -python          +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            -ruby            +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -X11
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xim
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      -sniff           -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop
+farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -I/usr/local/include  -g -    O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -ltinfo -    lnsl  -ldl
```

Comment: Unless I missed something, there doesn't seem to be a pre-built package for this; you'll have to build it from source...

Comment: Just to confirm, you have `vim-enhanced` installed, right?

Comment: @muru Sorry, I did the solution below before I could answer your question.  I don't recall having to uninstall vim-enhanced so it may have very well been the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed some points on this [thread](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=45388) and it got me up and running.  I think there are steps you can probably skip, but I have found this to be a working solution:

1) Remove installed vim

```
yum remove (all things vimish)
```

2) Remove other vim footprints

```
find / -name vim
```

3) Add software collection utility

```
yum -y install scl-utils
```

4) Add python repo

```
rpm -Uvh https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/python33/epel-7-x86_64/download/rhscl-python33-epel-7-x86_64.noarch.rpm
```

4) Install python

```
yum -y install python33
```

5) Install gvim

```
yum install gvim
```

6) Install vim-enhanced

```
yum install vim-enhanced.x86_64
```

7) Install sudo

```
yum install sudo
```

In vim do a :echo has('python') and it should return 1 which means you now have python support.  **Please be aware that you will be uninstalling sudo if you uninstall vim-minimal.  I think you should be okay if you copy your settings from visudo and repost after reinstalling sudo.

8) If the following occurs:

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/vim: No such file or directory
```

then do the following commands:

```
hash vim
vim
```

Details for this fix at this [link](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/forum/support/20140108/solved-bash-command-not-found-after-replacing-package)